# Create image blob using node-fetch

Tags: node.js, node-fetch

I am trying to get blob response using node-fetch unfortunately It is not working.

```
var fetch = require("node-fetch");


var respdata = fetch('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/77/Delete_key1.jpg')
  .then(res => res.blob()); // Gets the response and returns it as a blob 

console.log(respdata );
```

**Response:**

```
{}
```